# TextField's autofocus property causing the widget into 'dirty' State

Tags: dart, flutter

AppBar has a search icon, when clicked it displays a TextField in the 'title' property. When search icon is clicked I need TextField to  autofocus. Problem is with 'autofocus' property, if set to true, instead of only changing the state of the title property, something is causing the widget to turn into a 'dirty' state. This causes the main build function to get called which rebuilds the entire thing.

Tried to replicate this and provide a sample app but strangely enough it seems to work just fine in the demo.

Any debug suggestions?

```
     AppBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: false,
                      initialData: symbolBloc.isSearching,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot){
                        if(snapshot.data) {
                          return TextField(
    //                        autofocus: true, <--- here
                            controller: searchQuery,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          );
                        }

                        return new Text("", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                        );
                      }),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: bloc.isSearchActive,
                      initialData: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot){
                        if(snapshot.data)
                            return activeSearchIconButton(symbolBloc);
                        return searchIconButton(symbolBloc);
                      },

                    ),
                  ],
                ),

 searchIconButton(SymbolBloc bloc){
    return new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(
        Icons.search,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      tooltip: 'Search',
      onPressed: (){
        bloc.displaySearchField(true);
      },
    );
  }

  activeSearchIconButton(SymbolBloc bloc){
    return new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(
        Icons.close,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      tooltip: 'Search',
      onPressed: (){
        bloc.displaySearchField(false);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had do with InheritedWidgets. Having more than one InheritedWidget was the cause. I had a parent widget wrapping the runApp() function (holds a reference to api object) and a child widget wrapping each route (holds reference to bloc class for each specific screen).

Problem went away once I moved the contents of child widget over to the parent and removed the child InheritedWidget altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `FocusNode` property of `TextField` and on `Button` click call `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);`